# MQL4 How to make an array distinct?

Tags: arrays, mql4

I need to pick MagicNumbers into an Array, and then make the array distinct ( There are multiple order groups and each has unique MagicNumbers ). But having problem. My code is:

```
      int xxx = OrdersTotal();
      int magics[xxx];                               // here is an error:
                                                     //      invalid index value
      for ( int i = OrdersTotal() - 1; i >= 0; i-- ){

         if ( OrderSelect( i, SELECT_BY_POS ) ){

              magics[i] = OrderMagicNumber();        // choosing magics
              ArrayResize( magics,
                           ArraySize( magics ) + 1,
                           0
                           );
         }
      }

      ArraySort( magics );                           // making distinct
      int sorted[];
      int x = 0;
      for ( int i = 0; i < OrdersTotal() - 1; i++ ){ // duplicates = 0

         if ( magics[i] != magics[i+1] ){

              sorted[x] = magics[i];
              Print( "Sorted array: " + DoubleToStr( sorted[x] ) );
              x = x + 1;
         }
      }
```

How to pick distinct MagicNumbers into an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code. It will create an array, loop through all the orders in the History tab, check if the MagicNumber of the order exists in the array. If it does not exists, adds it to the array. You will end with an array of unique MagicNumbers.

```
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|                                                  UniqueMagic.mq4 |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
#property copyright "Copyright 2016, joseph dot lee at fs dot com dot my"
#property link      "https://www.facebook.com/joseph.fhlee"
#property strict
void OnTick() {
   int vaiMagicNumbers[];  //Array containing list of MagicNumbers

   //Loop through all the Orders (in History tab)
   for(int viIndex=OrdersTotal()-1; viIndex>=0; viIndex--) {
      if(OrderSelect(viIndex, SELECT_BY_POS, MODE_HISTORY) ){
         //Check if the selected Order (in History tab) already exists in the array
         if(  fniGetElementIndex( vaiMagicNumbers, OrderMagicNumber() ) == -1 ) {
            //If not exists, then increase the array by 1, and add the MagicNumber into the array
            ArrayResize(vaiMagicNumbers, ArrayRange(vaiMagicNumbers,0)+1);
            vaiMagicNumbers[ArrayRange(vaiMagicNumbers,0)-1] = OrderMagicNumber();
         }
      }
   };
   Comment( ArrayRange(vaiMagicNumbers,0) ); //Show the number of unique MagicNumbers in the History tab.
}

//Function to return the index (position) of viValue within a given array
int fniGetElementIndex( int &vaiArray[], int viValue ) {
   int   viElementCount = ArrayRange(vaiArray, 0); //Get the total number of elements within that array.
   int   viFoundAt = -1;                           //The element index where viValue is found within the array.

   //Loop through every element in vaiArray
   for(int viElement=0; viElement<viElementCount; viElement++) {
      if( vaiArray[viElement] == viValue ) {
         //If the element value is the same as viValue, then FOUND, break the for loop.
         viFoundAt = viElement;
         break;
      }
   }
   return( viFoundAt );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### `MQL4` concepts of array-alike objects and special Array Functions

First thing to say is, that MQL4 Array instrumentation is not so trivial as it might look on the first sight.

---

### What has caused the above reported error?

Compile-time declaration of an array size ( `int xxx`, depending on an a-priori unknown `OrdersTotal()` actual result, that is variable per se in the run-time epoch too ), shall be solved by either
**a static pre-allocation of the array**, say `int magicsARRAY[10000];` which allows compiler to preallocate memory and decides on the proper array-handling in run-time ( one may implement one's own stack-mechanics not to overflow on pointing behind the array tail-cell **[Ref. Warning below]** )
**or**
one may **declare an array as a variable-sized array** just by `int magicsARRAY[];` for the compiler phase and allow the run-time re-allocate the actual sizing with a context-aware **`ArrayResize(...);`** functionality on-demand.

It is fair to say, that a **good practice** in high-performance / low-latency code **shall avoid & prevent each & every memory re-allocation** during run-time.

---

### Next, on housekeeping services, that make `MagNUM`s into an Array

If memory ( `ArrayResize()` ) re-allocations are expensive during runtime, **the more are all the `dbPOOL` gymnastics** ( `OrderSelect()` + all the following OPs ).

Remember, your <kbd>**Expert Advisor**</kbd> code is entered and being executed **if and only if** there has been a market-event ( a price has just moved ), not in any other circumstances. So your code is reactive, ( in response to a price motion ) so you cannot spend a microsecond more on duties, that could be avoided.

Thus a professional code maintains static arrays as `MagNUM`-hash-tables, simply so as to avoid a blind-re-iterations through a **`dbPOOL`**. If you run <kbd>**Strategy Tester**</kbd> a lot, you must already know, how costly it is to re-iterate `dbPOOL` OPs during your optimisation batch-processing and how fast your optimisation problem runs, if you have zero-`dbPOOL` OPs down the road.

So the best way is to keep MagNUM-s right from the `OrderSend()` instantiations, throughout the life-cycle of the trade position and work with Array Functions instead of `OrderSelect()` + `OrderMagicNumber()` loops.

---

### Arrays can be quite toxic & dangerous in MQL4

If there is an attempt to access a cell outside of the array range, the **executing subsystem will generate a critical error and the program will be stopped. Which is something a Live-Trading engine shall never suffer from!**